# Pick a random number that is not is a set of number in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to pick a random number from 31 to 359.

```
rand(31, 359);
```

I need the number is not part from this array of numbers:

```
$badNumbers = array(30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360);
```

How can I do this please?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Looked at maybe [array functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)? Maybe review: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably do this as it completes when one is found:

```
while(in_array($rand = rand(31, 359), $badNumbers));
echo $rand;
```

Here is another way using an array:

```
$good  = array_diff(range(31, 359), $badNumbers);
echo $good[array_rand($good)];
```

Or randomize and choose one:

```
shuffle($good);
echo array_pop($good);
```

The array approaches are useful if you need to pick more than one random number. Think `array_rand` again or `array_slice` for the second one.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a *recursive function* (which is a function that keeps calling itself with a condition to break out once the requirement is met) or an infinite loop that breaks when it finds a number that isn't in the array. What this means is that you try to generate a number, but if that number is in the list, you try again - and keep doing that until satisfied.

Here's an example,

```php
$badNumbers = array(30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360);

function rand_unique(array $array, int $new) {
    if (in_array($new, $array)) {
        return rand_unique($array, $new);
    }
    return $new;
}
$newRand = rand_unique($badNumbers, rand(31, 359));
echo $newRand;
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/mhTFc

Answer (score 0):

This creates an array containing only the good numbers and returns a random value.

```
$goodNumbers = array_diff(range(31,359),[$badNumbers]);
$randIndex = array_rand($goodNumbers);
$randomGoodNumber = $goodNumbers[$randIndex];
```